# jQuery POST request - submitting a <form> inside of an <iframe>

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, post, cross-domain

I'm creating a quick prototype as a proof-of-concept for a bigger project. I need to create a working cross-domain POST request, and I have jQuery available.

Since I'm assuming (please correct me if I'm wrong) that $.ajax() will not work because the page making the POST request lives in a different domain than the server receiving the request, I'm guessing that the best solution is to use JavaScript to create an <iframe>, insert a <form method="post"> in there that includes hidden inputs with my POST data, and submit it.

How exactly would I do this? (Please provide code examples if possible.)

So far, I have this:

```
<button type="button" name="button">Make Cross-Domain POST Request</button>

<script>
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('body').append('<iframe id="post_frame" style="width: 0; height: 0; border: none;"></iframe>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      var frame_body = $('#post_frame').contents().find('body');
      frame_body.append('<form action="..." method="post"><input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" /><input type="submit" /></form>');
      // not sure what goes here (should submit the form in the iframed document once it has loaded)
    }, 1);
  });
</script>
```

I know that I need to use the submit() method, but I don't know exactly what that looks like, especially since the <form> is within an <iframe> and I should only call submit() after that <iframe> has loaded.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions/ideas, spot any errors, could recommend a better approach, etc. Thanks in advance!

(Incidentally, I did some searching on Stack Overflow days ago and could have sworn that I found some code in a related question that would have been helpful. I can't find that today, though...)

Answer (score 4):

`p` is an array of post variables and `to` is your action

```
   var issuePOST = function(to, p) {
        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = "post";
        myForm.action = to;
        if (p) {
            for (var k in p) {
                var myInput = document.createElement("input");
                myInput.setAttribute("name", k);
                myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
                myForm.appendChild(myInput);
            }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(myForm);
        myForm.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(myForm);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but I'd like to use jQuery to enhance cross-browser compatibility, and I think I need to use an <iframe> so that the page's URL doesn't change.

Comment: This code above should work for all browsers, it uses basic javascript that is the same accross all browsers. And you can put it within an iframe...

Comment: to resolve your cross domain issue, you don't need to use iframe. You can make your ajax request use jsonp object which works accross domains. Simply within an ajax call add datatype:jsonp and it will work cross domain.

Comment: Dude, you just saved me from pulling *all* of my hair out :-)  The *key* element of your suggestion here is "document.body".  For some reason this required when posting from within an iframe.  Otherwise, just using "document" is sufficient ... I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript snippet in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597548/form-post-in-iframe-without-affecting-history) will post cross-domain from an IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$("#post_frame").contents().find('form').submit();
```

after the append.